# Newly added components are pushing older items already added on top to top making the older items overlap each other

Tags: html, css

I am building a landing page using html, css. I was adding components sequentially downwards. But after adding a few components, the newer components starting pushing older components to the top. What could be the possible sources of this error? Sharing little code as i have little time. Will add more code later. Any direction till then will be much appreciated. PS: I am using CSS flexbox and pretty much gave same css properties to both old components and new components.

CSS

```
.root {
    width: 1440px;
    height: 7600px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}

.container__main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 1440px;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    border-radius: 80px 80px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container__curator {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 135px;
    width: 876.06px;
    height: 541px;
}


.container__perks {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: stretch;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 241px;
    width: 1229.2px;
    height: 518.09px;
}

.container__roadmap {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 241px;
    width: 1178px;
    height: 350px;
}

.container__accordion {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 210px;
    width: 708px;
    height: 664px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="root">
<div class="container__main">
<div class="container__perks">
<div class="container__roadmap">
<div class="container__accordion">
..
..
<div class="container__accordion">
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Error: Overlap of older components]

What could be the possible sources of this error? Thankyou.

Comment: It's because of the margin-top you applied to each component.

Comment: @Amini didnt fix it. position property is right here?